# VACUUM cannot run inside a transaction block

Tags: postgresql, jdbc

My application has this code:

```
Connection connection = DriverManager.getConnection(url, userName, password);
connection.setAutoCommit(false);
try {
    Statement statement = connection.createStatement();
    try {
        statement.executeUpdate("TRUNCATE mytable");
    } finally {
        statement.close();
    }
    connection.commit();
    connection.setAutoCommit(true);
    statement = connection.createStatement();
    try {
        statement.executeUpdate("VACUUM mytable");
    } finally {
        statement.close();
    }
    connection.setAutoCommit(false);
    connection.commit();
} finally {
    connection.close();
}
```

It fails on `statement.executeUpdate("VACUUM mytable");` because `VACUUM cannot run inside a transaction block`.

I must be missing some notions as I thought that setting the autocommit to `true` would remove the transaction context (needed for `TRUNCATE`). Apparently it doesn't. So how do I get out of the transactional context and perform my VACUUM successfully? How should I write my code to not have this transactional context?

Comment: Unrelated, but: you don't need to create another `Statement` instance just to run a different SQL statement. But I agree, this should work. Does using `execute()` instead of `executeUpdate()` change anything?

Comment: I've launched my test with `execute()` instead of `executeUpdate()`. It takes quite some time so meanwhile, what do you mean when you say I don't need another `Statement`? I should run `statement.executeUpdate("TRUNCATE mytable"); connection.commit(); connection.setAutoCommit(true); statement.execute("VACUUM mytable");` in a single `try {} finally {}` block?

Comment: If it now runs for some time this could either mean it's waiting for a lock or that the `vacuum` is actually doing something.  The second `statement = connection.createStatement();` is simply not necessary. You can use a single instance for multiple calls. Whether or not you want that in a single `try` block is up to you.

Comment: Regarding the length of the test, I meant simply that this is only part of a (much) more lengthy procedure and I unfortunately cannot isolate the test at the moment as I have to run the whole procedure to check this specifically (I should definitely install a db on my computer). Now that it's over, it actually works. So thanks for that. If you want some rep, post your answer, I'll accept it. Also, thanks for the update on `statement`.